# Is it possible to POST a text file containg a comma seperated list to a Spring MVC service?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app, and I need to post a comma separated list to the service. I have ti working with a JSON request, but need to do the same with text file. So my curl request would look like this:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:8080/myservice" -d @list.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Your controller should accept the "text/csv" mime type

You can use Jackson 2 to marshall CSV to Java classes if you want:

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_468.html